# Bootstrap 3 Grid alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, bootstrap-4, responsive

Good Day all you Geniuses

I need help with some bootstrap grid alignment, the problem I face is when it goes in responsive mode it does stack like I need it to stack. I'd really appreciate some help with getting this to fold and stack the right way so that it is all neat on mobile devices.

If someone can just help me with the skeleton without styling I'd really appreciate it, and ill go and style.

I have two example images, one in full view and one which is how it needs to stack or fold to.

[image]
[image]

```
This is my code
```

```css
div.parent { 
    border  : solid black 1px;
    display : table;
    padding : 5px; 
    width   : 100%;
  /* you can change/remove margin */
    margin   :5px 0; 
  }
div.text { 
    vertical-align : middle;
    display        : table-cell;
    text-align     : justify;
}
div.parent .img {
    vertical-align   : middle;
    display          : table-cell;
    padding-right    : 5px;
    width            : 100px; /* you can change width */
}
div.img img { 
    width           : 100%;
    /* you can change height */
    vertical-align   : middle;
}


.my_planHeader {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top:0.2em;
    padding-bottom:0.2em;
}
.my_planTitle {
    font-size:1em;
 color: #000;
}
.my_subTitle {
    font-size:0.80em;
 color: #A64470 ;
 color: #000;
}
.my_planPrice {
    font-size:0.80em;
    font-weight: bold;
 color: #C0BBBB;    
}
.my_disc {
    font-size:1.4em;
    font-weight: bold; 
 color: #C0BBBB;    
}
.my_planDuration {
    margin-top: -0.6em;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .my_planTitle {
        font-size:small;
    }    
}


 

/* --- TRANSFERS --------------------------- */

.my_plan1 {
    background: rgb(224,234,242);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan1 a {
    background: rgb(72, 109, 139);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan1 {
    background: #FEF6ED;
    border-bottom: thick solid #FEEAD2;
}



/* --- FEE --------------------------- */
.my_plan2 {
    background: rgb(230,235,218);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan2 a {
    background: rgb(108, 131, 62);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan2 {
    background: #FCDFD1;
    border-bottom: thick solid #FEF1EC;
}

/* --- APR --------------------------- */
.my_plan3 {
    background: rgb(254,235,212);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan3 a {
    background: rgb(199, 127, 40);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan3 {
    background: #F7D5DF;
    border-bottom: thick solid #FBEDF1;
}

/* --- OVER --------------------------- */


.my_plan4 {
    background: rgb(254,235,212);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan4 a {
    background: rgb(199, 127, 40);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan4 {
    background: #EAD3DD;
    border-bottom: thick solid #F7D5DF;
}
/* --- OVER --------------------------- */


.my_plan5 {
    background: rgb(254,235,212);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan5 a {
    background: rgb(199, 127, 40);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan5 {
    background: #F8F8F8;
    border-bottom: thick solid #C0BBBB;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">



<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="row">     



<div class="parent">
<div class="img">
<div class="col-lg-12 ">
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/90x90" class="img-responsive" alt="Some picture" width="150" height="150">
</div></div>
    
    <div class="text">
    <div class="col-lg-3 my_planHeader my_plan1">
    <div class="my_subTitle">Balance Transfers</div>
    <div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 my_planHeader my_plan2">
    <div class="my_subTitle">Balance Transfers</div>
    <div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 my_planHeader my_plan3">
    <div class="my_subTitle">Balance Transfers</div>
    <div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 my_planHeader my_plan1">
    <div class="my_subTitle">Balance Transfers</div>
    <div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-12 ">
    <p>Free aqua credit checker. Start with a credit limit of £250-£1,200 and you    could get an increase on your 4th statement.
    Once the 0% deal ends the balance transfer rate will be 34.95% p.a. variable with a 3% fee.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-12 my_planHeader my_plan3">
    <div class="my_subTitle">Balance Transfers</div>
    <div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

[This is how it is wrapping now on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQuVY.png)

Comment: This is my code

Comment: @Luke this is a picture. Can you please show us what you have tried, in terms of code ? You can edit the question to add it

Comment: https://codepen.io/mdxsolutions/pen/EbVByq

Comment: Sorry its doesnt allow me to add this links

Comment: @Luke I don't really understand the problem. You suggest from the second image that it should wrap like this. From your example I see that it does wrap like this. How exactly do you want it to work?

Comment: Hi no it does wrap like that the image still remains on the left side. the text and colums are all aligned. the secon last colum is going to be a button so that can wrap under the last colum or ontop it doesnt matter, however the image needs to be the same size as the other wraped itmes,and it needs to be at the very top.

Comment: Please click on the link where i say this is how it wraps now, the image needs to move to the top, it stays on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/90x90" class="img-responsive" alt="Some picture" width="100%" height="150"></div>
  <div class="col-sm my_planHeader my_plan1"><div class="lukeStuff">Balance Transfers</div><div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div></div>
  <div class="col-sm my_planHeader my_plan2"><div class="lukeStuff">Balance Transfers</div><div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div></div>
  <div class="col-sm my_planHeader my_plan3"><div class="lukeStuff">Balance Transfers</div><div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><p>Free aqua credit checker. Start with a credit limit of £250-£1,200 and you    could get an increase on your 4th statement.Once the 0% deal ends the balance transfer rate will be 34.95% p.a. variable with a 3% fee.</p></div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 my_planHeader my_plan3"><div class="lukeStuff">Balance Transfers</div><div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div></div>
</div>
```

```css
    div.parent { 
    border  : solid black 1px;
    display : table;
    padding : 5px; 
    width   : 100%;
  /* you can change/remove margin */
    margin   :5px 0; 
  }
div.text { 
    vertical-align : middle;
    display        : table-cell;
    text-align     : justify;
}
div.parent .img {
    vertical-align   : middle;
    display          : table-cell;
    padding-right    : 5px;
    width            : 100px; /* you can change width */
}
div.img img { 
    width           : 100%;
    /* you can change height */
    vertical-align   : middle;
}


.my_planHeader {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top:0.2em;
    padding-bottom:0.2em;
}
.my_planTitle {
    font-size:1em;
 color: #000;
}
.my_subTitle {
    font-size:0.80em;
 color: #A64470 ;
 color: #000;
}
.my_planPrice {
    font-size:0.80em;
    font-weight: bold;
 color: #C0BBBB;    
}
.my_disc {
    font-size:1.4em;
    font-weight: bold; 
 color: #C0BBBB;    
}
.my_planDuration {
    margin-top: -0.6em;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .my_planTitle {
        font-size:small;
    }    
}


 

/* --- TRANSFERS --------------------------- */

.my_plan1 {
    background: rgb(224,234,242);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan1 a {
    background: rgb(72, 109, 139);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan1 {
    background: #FEF6ED;
    border-bottom: thick solid #FEEAD2;
}



/* --- FEE --------------------------- */
.my_plan2 {
    background: rgb(230,235,218);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan2 a {
    background: rgb(108, 131, 62);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan2 {
    background: #FCDFD1;
    border-bottom: thick solid #FEF1EC;
}

/* --- APR --------------------------- */
.my_plan3 {
    background: rgb(254,235,212);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan3 a {
    background: rgb(199, 127, 40);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan3 {
    background: #F7D5DF;
    border-bottom: thick solid #FBEDF1;
}

/* --- OVER --------------------------- */


.my_plan4 {
    background: rgb(254,235,212);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan4 a {
    background: rgb(199, 127, 40);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan4 {
    background: #EAD3DD;
    border-bottom: thick solid #F7D5DF;
}
/* --- OVER --------------------------- */


.my_plan5 {
    background: rgb(254,235,212);
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan5 a {
    background: rgb(199, 127, 40);
    color:white;
}

.my_planHeader.my_plan5 {
    background: #F8F8F8;
    border-bottom: thick solid #C0BBBB;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/90x90" class="img-responsive" alt="Some picture" width="100%" height="150"></div>
  <div class="col-sm my_planHeader my_plan1"><div class="lukeStuff">Balance Transfers</div><div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div></div>
  <div class="col-sm my_planHeader my_plan2"><div class="lukeStuff">Balance Transfers</div><div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div></div>
  <div class="col-sm my_planHeader my_plan3"><div class="lukeStuff">Balance Transfers</div><div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><p>Free aqua credit checker. Start with a credit limit of £250-£1,200 and you    could get an increase on your 4th statement.Once the 0% deal ends the balance transfer rate will be 34.95% p.a. variable with a 3% fee.</p></div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 my_planHeader my_plan3"><div class="lukeStuff">Balance Transfers</div><div class="my_planTitle">0% for 24 months</div></div>
</div>
```